# How to list the loaded module paths in Xamarin Studio?

Tags: c#, module, nuget, portable-class-library, xamarin-studio

I'm trying to debug an incorrectly loaded assembly - it looks like the wrong platform version has somehow been loaded for a NuGet package.

How can I display the list and full path of all loaded modules in Xamarin studio?

Visual Studio has a "Modules" window that shows this.

Answer (score 0):

1) You can look in the bin/Debug (Release) directory as a local copy of all the references that are used to package the `.app`/`.apk` will be there

2) If you have the `Properties` Pad open (on the right-side of the IDE), you can cycle through your references and the physical location "Path" of the assembly that is being used will be shown (along with version, package, name...)

3) You can open the `Assembly Browser` view and cycle through the top-level references on the left and see the resulting assembly attributes, info, c# or IL code, etc...

4) You can use `monodis` to see the referenced assemblies of your app's main dll, i.e.`monodis --assemblyref BlueToothTransfer.dll`

5) `ikdasm` which is more of  a direct disasm replacement of `ldasm.exe`

Answer (score 0):

NuGet packages that use the ["bait and switch"](http://ericsink.com/entries/pcl_bait_and_switch.html) approach to Portable Class Libraries are tricky, because the "bait" assembly that you code against is not the one actually loaded.

The only definitive way I've found to know what modules are actually loaded, as opposed to "ought to load", is to look in the Application Output debugger window. During startup, it outputs the full path to each assembly as it is loaded.